# hand optimising javascript selector function

Tags: javascript, optimization

I personally want a small selector function that covers the three common cases

- getElementById
- getElementsByClassName
- getElementsByTagName

It should support contexts and should not support `querySelectorAll` since `<opinionated>` QSA is slow as hell and should be avoided `</opinionated>`

I have an implementation of such a [function](https://gist.github.com/1455456)

```
function select(selector, context) {
    var c = selector.charAt(0),
        method;

    if (c === "#") {
        method = "getElementById";
        selector = selector.substring(1);
    } else if (c === ".") {
        method = "getElementsByClassName";
        selector = selector.substring(1);
    } else {
        method = "getElementsByTagName";
    }

    return (context || document)[method](selector);
}
```

And I have a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery).

As can be seen it's still a factor of 4 away from native support.

Can I hand optimise this further? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

This is twice as slow as native (the original being 4x as slow)

```
function select (selector, context) {
    var c = selector.charAt(0), 
        method,
        context = context || document;

    if (c === '#') {
        selector = selector.substring(1);
        method = context.getElementById(selector);
    } 

    else if (c === '.') {
        selector = selector.substring(1);
        method = context.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    } 

    else {
        method = context.getElementsByTagName(selector);
    }

    return method
}
```

Comment: [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery) confirm your function is either the same or faster.

Comment: anything else that could be done?

Comment: Fork chrome/firefox and hand optimise their C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Well , you have to keep in mind that not all browsers implement `getElementsByClassName`, not even all of ( what you would call ) "proper browsers".

You should add a fallback for such a problem.

That said, you probably could get rid of at least one `IF` , if you use something like a `{ '.': 'getElementsByClassName', '#': 'getElementById' };`. Just put said object into closure, otherwise you would be creating it each time anew.

Comment: I know `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in IE8, I have a shim for that.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion as [select2](http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery). It's actually slightly slower.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why no one has suggested a `switch` ?

As i understand it a switch will be equal or faster than if statements *EDIT:- except chrome ... huh!?*

```
switch(c)
{
    case '#':
        ...
        break; // or return
    case '.':
        ...
        break; // or return
    default
        ...
        break; // or return
}
```

http://jsperf.com/select-vs-natives-vs-jquery/6